# Get-WindowsFeatures: how to filter on Display Name?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I am working with Windows Server 2016. 
The PowerShell's `Get-WindowsFeature` cmdlet gives its output in 3 fields: **Display Name**, **Name** and **Install State**. As per documentation I can filter on **Name** field but I want to filter on **Display Name** field. How can I do that? 
Also I can see there is hierarchy some times in values of **Display Name** field. For example *.NET Framework 3.5 Features* has 3 child items. I want to be able to filter on *.NET Framework 3.5 Features* **Display Name** field and can also see its child items. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where-Object` and `-like` or `-match`

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object displayname -like '*framework 3.5*'

Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object displayname -match 'framework 3\.5'
```

Even though it shows `Display Name` in the formatted output, it's actually `DisplayName` as the property name. You can see all its properties by using `Get-Member`

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Get-Member
```

Comment: Actually, the `-match` uses regex, so you should escape the dot (or any other character that has special meaning in regex) by prefixing it with a backslash.

Comment: You’re absolutely right. My test was just with “framework”. Good looking out Theo.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_."Display Name" -like "*yoursearch*"}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$search = Get-WindowsFeature "NET-Framework-Features"
$search.subfeatures
```